# FFMPEG - pan across image without zoom in or out

Tags: ffmpeg

I am trying to create a 5 second video of an image and pan across the image. I am familiar with the [zoompan](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#zoompan) video filter and I can get the result as desired with zooming in or out. But, I need to be able to just pan across the image without zooming in or out. How can I accomplish this? The current command I have to apply a simple zoomin to the middle right of the image is:

```
ffmpeg -y -framerate 25 -loop 1 -i img-1.png -filter_complex "[0:v]scale=5120x2880,zoompan=z='min(zoom+0.0005,1.5)':x='5120':y='ih/2-(ih/zoom/2)':d=125,trim=duration=5" -crf 1 -preset ultrafast out.mp4
```

How can I change the filter to accomplish ONLY the pan from the middle to the right without the zoom in?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like a job for crop filter. Something like

`crop=iw/2:ih:iw/2*t/5:0`

Comment: What if I don't want to move the entire image? All I want to do is pan from the center of the image to different parts of the image like: top, top-right, right, bottom-right, bottom, bottom-left, left, and top-left. How can I start in the center of the image, maybe even slightly zoomed in so the image fills the dimensions throughout the entire pan, and move to one of those positions?

Comment: Then use something like

`crop=iw/2:2*ih/3:iw/4*(1+t/5):ih/6*(1+t/5)`

Anyway, any pan effect without zoom can be imagined as covering the picture with some cover with a hole in it, and moving that cover over the picture; crop filter does exactly that.

Comment: Can you explain a little about how that command is working and what each part is doing?

Comment: To do this with the zoompan filter, set the zoom option to a fixed value i.e. `z=1.5` and animate the `x` and `y` parameters. Although I would prefer the crop myself.

Comment: what is the entire command? I get only one frame in my video when I try something like ffmpeg -i image.jpg -filter_complex "[0:v]crop=iw/2:ih:iw/2*t/5:0,trim=duration=5" -c:a copy output.mp4 @Mulvya

Comment: Add `-loop 1` before `-i`